# Linker error when referencing static NSString const in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm still in the process of learning Swift, but I have a pretty good understanding of the basics and how it interacts with Objective-C. On my team, we have an Objective-C app and we're experimenting with some Swift in the app. Our standard in the past has been to put our constants in a header file like:

`static NSString *const kSomeConstant = @"ConstantValue";`

But when I reference this value in Swift, I get a linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_kSomeConstant", referenced from:
>         __TFFC22Commons_Tests36DCTestBTBusinessService25testSuccessfulFetchOffersFS0_FT_T_u0_KT_PSs11BooleanType_
>   in DCTestBTBusinessService.o ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I change the static const to a #define it compiles successfully but this is not ideal if not necessary. Any idea why this is not linking? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here is an example of where we are trying to use the value. The CacheManager class is an Objective-C class and containsObjectForKey accepts an NSString as a parameter.

`CacheManager.instance().containsObjectForKey(kSomeConstant)`

Comment: Sorry, we're using the stable version of XCode currently (6.1.1) so I think that would be Swift 1.1?

Comment: Updated with an example of using the value in Swift.

Comment: kSomeConstant is a static NSString *const. This isn't a compile error though this is a linking error so I'm not sure how relevant the Swift code actually is

Comment: Well whenever we reference a static NSString * const in a Swift file in our project it's giving us a linking error. I'm hoping there is a setting in the project we can set.

Comment: I think your problem might be that you're using `static`. In C that means that the variable is local to the file it's defined in. Since you define in it a .h file, that makes it local to every .m/.c file that includes it. Which ends up meaning: there's no actual `kSomeConstant` symbol, but rather a private mangled symbol for each include made.